# Meaning Of Spring Cron Expression "*/5 * * * * ?"

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I used spring scheduler with cron expression

> */5 * * * * ?

(for every 5 seconds) . It's worked for last one month, suddenly it's stopped in last two days.

After Restarting server again it's working fine.

Is there any difference between

> */5 * * * * ?
>   */5 * * * * *

? it's based on any month basis.

So what is the meaning of **?** here. 
Want to know the reason why it's stopped?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe it never finished, there is a quartz setting that allows you to configure this situation

Answer (score 6):

Here "

> *

means  **all values**. 
For example, dayofmonth="*" means run the process every day.

> "?"

is used only for dayofmonth and dayofweek attribute

and means "without regard to this value" 
For example, hours="12" dayofweek="MON-FRI" dayofmonth="?" means "Run at noon every weekday (without regard to the day of the month)".

> ","

separates multiple values. 
For example, dayofweek="MON,FRI" means every Monday and Friday. Do not includes spaces after the comma.

> "/"

specifies increments. For example, minutes="0/15" means start at minute 0 and run every 15 minutes.

"L" is used only for dayofmonth and dayofweek and means "the last day of the month/week".

Comment: What's the exact difference between '?' and '*'. I believe they both result in the same output?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Quartz documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)  :

> The ‘?’ character is allowed for the day-of-month and day-of-week
>   fields. It is used to specify “no specific value”. This is useful when
>   you need to specify something in one of the two fields, but not the
>   other. See the examples below (and CronTrigger JavaDoc) for
>   clarification.